# Where is Import Table in ELF file?

Tags: linux, elf, import-table

I found ".dynsym" in String Table, got index. 
Then I found section with sh_name = index && sh_type = SHT_DYNSYM.
So I got sh_offset = 464 and sh_size = 64. 
But you can see in the attached picture, that on the offset 464 there are only zeros.

I suppose that Import Table starts on offset 528. Question is: how calculate it %)

> [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But you can see in the attached picture, that on the offset 464 there are only zeros.

Wrong: `01`, `20`, `29`, `12` etc. are *not* "only zeros" last time I checked.

> I suppose that Import Table starts on offset 528

No, it does not. For some reason you are expecting to find a Microsoft `PE`-style import table in an ELF file. It's not there.

An *equivalent* of an import table in ELF is contained in *two* tables. One contains `Elf{32,64}_Sym` fixed-size records:

```
typedef struct
{
  Elf32_Word    st_name;                /* Symbol name (string tbl index) */
  Elf32_Addr    st_value;               /* Symbol value */
  Elf32_Word    st_size;                /* Symbol size */
  unsigned char st_info;                /* Symbol type and binding */
  unsigned char st_other;               /* Symbol visibility */
  Elf32_Section st_shndx;               /* Section index */
} Elf32_Sym;
```

and is contained in the `.dynsym` section.

The other table is contained in `.dynstr` section (which, in your file starts at offset 528), and has just the (variable-size) strings separated by `NUL` character.

The `.st_name` in the first table refers to offset in `.dynstr`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. But on the offset 464 there is no Elf32_Sym record. sh_offset = 464 I got from header of .dynsym section. Weirdly that sh_size = 64 and in the same time sizeof(Elf32_Sym) = 16.

Comment: I just have caught a thought. May be those 64 bytes are 4 records (Elf32_Sym)?